# Drag and Drop feature in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

As you can see, there is a drag feature here. Everything is working perfectly, but when I drag TrainLeft or TrainRight, I can only see them inside the ScrollView while I am moving them. I want to see TrainLeft and TrainRight outside of the ScrollView while I am moving them.I will use the StationMap inside another window. In fact, when I use a Grid instead of a ScrollView, it worked. So when I used this approach, it worked, but I need to add MergeStationTrain automatically.

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="200*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="200*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<local:MergeStationTrain ShowLeft="True"
                         ShowRight="False"
                         ShowFireLeft="False"
                         ShowDoorLeft="False"
                         TrainName="12345"
                         StationName="A"/>
<local:MergeStationTrain ShowLeft="False"
                         ShowRight="False"
                         TrainName="12345"
                         StationName="B"
                         Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>

<UserControl x:Class="LibUI.UI.View.MainWindow.StationMap"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LibUI.UI.View.MainWindow"
         xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:LibUI.Converter"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="900" 
         d:DesignWidth="1800"
         Background="{StaticResource BackgroundMainBrush}">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <converter:ScrollBarVisibilityConverter x:Key="ScrollBarVisibilityConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

    <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}"
                      PreviewMouseMove="ItemsControl_PreviewMouseMove"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="10,10,0,10">
                        <local:MergeStationTrain/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>

</UserControl>

public partial class StationMap : UserControl
{ 
   public ObservableCollection<MergeStationTrain> DataList { get; } = new 
   ObservableCollection<MergeStationTrain>();

public MergeStationTrain this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        return DataList[index];
    }
    set
    {
        DataList[index] = value;
    }
}

public Database database { get; set; } = null;

public StationMap()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}

public async Task UpdateMap()
{
    DataList.Clear();
    string query = QueryManager.GetQuery(QueryType.SelectAllStations);
    List<StationInfo> list = await database.GetTableAsync<StationInfo>(query, tableName: 
    "t_station");
    foreach (StationInfo item in list)
    {
        MergeStationTrain newItem = new MergeStationTrain()
        {
            StationName = item.stnName,
            TrainName = item.stnNo,
            ShowLeft = true,
            ShowRight = true
        };

        DataList.Add(newItem);
    } 
   } 
} 

<UserControl x:Class="LibUI.UI.View.MainWindow.MergeStationTrain"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:LibUI.Converter"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LibUI.UI.View.MainWindow"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="200">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <converter:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibialityConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>


<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Margin="10, 10, 20, 0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
    <local:TrainLeft TrainName="{Binding TrainName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
      AncestorType=UserControl}}"
      ShowFire="{Binding ShowFireLeft, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
      AncestorType=UserControl}}"
      ShowDoor="{Binding ShowDoorLeft, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
      AncestorType=UserControl}}"
      Visibility="{Binding ShowLeft, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
      AncestorType=UserControl}, Converter={StaticResource VisibialityConverter}}">
    </local:TrainLeft>
    <local:Station Title="{Binding StationName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
             AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
             Grid.Row="1"/>
    <local:TrainRight TrainName="{Binding TrainName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
             AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
             ShowFire="{Binding ShowFireRight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
             AncestorType=UserControl}}"
             ShowDoor="{Binding ShowDoorRight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
             AncestorType=UserControl}}"
             Visibility="{Binding ShowRight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
             AncestorType=UserControl}, Converter={StaticResource VisibialityConverter}}"
             Grid.Row="2">
    </local:TrainRight>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>


public partial class TrainRight : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TrainNameProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("TrainName", typeof(string), typeof(TrainRight));
     
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowFireProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("ShowFire", typeof(bool), typeof(TrainRight), new PropertyMetadata(false, ShowFirePropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowDoorProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("ShowDoor", typeof(bool), typeof(TrainRight), new PropertyMetadata(false, ShowDoorPropertyChanged));
       
    public bool ShowFire
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowFireProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ShowFireProperty, value); }
    }

    public bool ShowDoor
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowDoorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ShowDoorProperty, value); }
    }

    public string TrainName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TrainNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TrainNameProperty, value); }
    }

    private ElementAdorner _elementAdorner = default!;

    public TrainRight()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;

        MouseMove += DragControl_MouseMove;
        PreviewGiveFeedback += DragControl_PreviewGiveFeedback;
    }

    private void DragControl_PreviewGiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
        _elementAdorner.SetArrange(this);
    }

    private void DragControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        AdornerLayer adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this);
        _elementAdorner = new ElementAdorner(this);
        adornerLayer.Add(_elementAdorner);

        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, this.DataContext, DragDropEffects.Copy);

        adornerLayer.Remove(_elementAdorner);
    }

    private static void ShowFirePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, 
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TrainRight trainLeft = (TrainRight)d;
        bool show = (bool)e.NewValue;
         
        if (show)
        {
            ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(trainLeft.imFire,
            (ImageSource)Application.Current.FindResource("FireGif"));
            ImageBehavior.SetRepeatBehavior(trainLeft.imFire, RepeatBehavior.Forever);
        }
        else
        {
            ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(trainLeft.imFire, null);
        }
    }

    private static void ShowDoorPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, 
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TrainRight trainLeft = (TrainRight)d;
        bool show = (bool)e.NewValue;
      
        if (show)
        {
            ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(trainLeft.imDoor,
           (ImageSource)Application.Current.FindResource("DoorGif"));
            ImageBehavior.SetRepeatBehavior(trainLeft.imDoor, RepeatBehavior.Forever);
        }
        else
        {
            ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(trainLeft.imDoor, null);
        }
    }
}

public partial class TrainLeft : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TrainNameProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("TrainName", typeof(string), typeof(TrainLeft));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowFireProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("ShowFire", typeof(bool), typeof(TrainLeft), new 
      PropertyMetadata(false, ShowFirePropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowDoorProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("ShowDoor", typeof(bool), typeof(TrainLeft), new
      PropertyMetadata(false, ShowDoorPropertyChanged));

    public bool ShowFire
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowFireProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ShowFireProperty, value); }
    }

    public bool ShowDoor
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowDoorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ShowDoorProperty, value); }
    }

    public string TrainName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TrainNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TrainNameProperty, value); }
    }

    private ElementAdorner _elementAdorner = default!;

    public TrainLeft()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;

        MouseMove += DragControl_MouseMove;
        PreviewGiveFeedback += DragControl_PreviewGiveFeedback;
    }

    private void DragControl_PreviewGiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
        _elementAdorner.SetArrange(this);
    }

    private void DragControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        AdornerLayer adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this);
        _elementAdorner = new ElementAdorner(this);
        adornerLayer.Add(_elementAdorner);

        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, this.DataContext, DragDropEffects.Copy);

        adornerLayer.Remove(_elementAdorner);
    }
     
    private static void ShowFirePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, 
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TrainLeft trainLeft = (TrainLeft)d;
        bool show = (bool)e.NewValue;
         
        if (show)
        {
            ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(trainLeft.imFire, 
            (ImageSource)Application.Current.FindResource("FireGif"));
            ImageBehavior.SetRepeatBehavior(trainLeft.imFire, RepeatBehavior.Forever);
        }
        else
        {
            ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(trainLeft.imFire, null);
        }
    }

    private static void ShowDoorPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, 
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TrainLeft trainLeft = (TrainLeft)d;
        bool show = (bool)e.NewValue;
         
        if (show)
        {
            ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(trainLeft.imDoor,
           (ImageSource)Application.Current.FindResource("DoorGif"));
            ImageBehavior.SetRepeatBehavior(trainLeft.imDoor, RepeatBehavior.Forever);
        }
        else
        {
            ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(trainLeft.imDoor, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I remove 'ScrollViewer', it works, but stationMap still needs to be scrollable.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop?